# How to simulate sound emission properties of the human body?

Tags: sound-isolation

Is there any way to simulate sound transmission properties of the human body with solid materials?

While there are several sound sources inside the human body (heartbeat, air flow, bubbles moving inside the intestines) only a very small amount is transferred to the sourrounding air. It can however be tapped on by a stethoscope in a quite efficient fashion.

Is this process comparable to sound in and over water, where sounds sources underwater can be heard well underwater but almost nothing leaves the water?

Is it possible to create a solid body that would transmit almost no sound to the air, but can be tapped on with a stethoscope?

Comment: How about using ultrasonic?

Comment: If I tap ultrasonic via a stethoscope, it keeps ultrasonic and I hear nothing I guess... so no good simulation of human body sounds.

Answer (score 2):

Use a *ballistics dummy*.

Ballistics dummies are designed and constructed to approximate the mechanical properties of the human body. They consist primarily of a molded ballistics gel designed for the same purpose. They are used most commonly for ballistics testing done by forensics and crime labs.

Ballistics Dummy

[image]

Comment: I guess I go for silicone. It seems to be more durable and would have a more skin-like appearance if colored. The accoustic parameters are not so different from water, which is the main component of the body and of balistic gel I guess?